# Erro "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, syntax-error

Estava tentando rodar um programa bem simples pelo terminal (uso ubuntu gnome):

```
#encoding: utf-8
y = int(input("Ultimo número: "))
x=0
while x <= y
   if x % 2 == 0
     print (x)
   x=x+1
```

e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

```
File "pares.py", line 4

    while x <= y
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Qual é a causa do problema nesse caso?

Answer (score 4):

Faltou o `:` no `while` e no `if`, faça assim:

```
#encoding: utf-8
y = int(input("Ultimo número: "))
x=0
while x <= y:
   if x % 2 == 0:
     print (x)
   x=x+1
```

Segue doc: http://wiki.python.org.br/DocumentacaoPython